# extract number of days in month from date column, return days to date in current month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with a date column

I'm trying to create a function and apply it to the dataframe to create a column that returns the number of days in the month/year specified

so far i have:

```
from calendar import monthrange

def dom(x):
    m = dfs["load_date"].dt.month
    y = dfs["load_date"].dt.year
    monthrange(y,m)
    days = monthrange[1]
    return days
```

This however does not work when I attempt to apply it to the date column.

Additionally, I would like to be able to identify whether or not it is the current month, and if so return the number of days up to the current date in that month as opposed to days in the entire month.

I am not sure of the best way to do this, all I can think of is to check the month/year against datetime's today and then use a delta

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **pt.1** of your question, you can cast to `pd.Period` and retrieve `days_in_month`:

```
import pandas as pd
# create a sample df:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-01', '2021-01', freq='M')})

df['daysinmonths'] = df['date'].apply(lambda t: pd.Period(t, freq='S').days_in_month)
# df['daysinmonths']
# 0     31
# 1     29
# 2     31
# ...
```

For **pt.2**, you can take the timestamp of 'now' and create a boolean mask for your date column, i.e. where its year/month is less than "now". Then calculate the cumsum of the daysinmonth column for the section where the mask returns True. Invert the order of that series to get the days *until* now.

```
now = pd.Timestamp('now')
m = (df['date'].dt.year <= now.year) & (df['date'].dt.month < now.month)
df['daysuntilnow'] = df['daysinmonths'][m].cumsum().iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

*Update after comment:* to get the elapsed days per month, you can do

```
df['dayselapsed'] = df['daysinmonths']
m = (df['date'].dt.year == now.year) & (df['date'].dt.month == now.month)
if m.any():
    df.loc[m, 'dayselapsed'] = now.day
df.loc[(df['date'].dt.year >= now.year) & (df['date'].dt.month > now.month), 'dayselapsed'] = 0
```

output

```
df
Out[13]: 
         date  daysinmonths  daysuntilnow  dayselapsed
0  2020-01-31            31         213.0           31
1  2020-02-29            29         182.0           29
2  2020-03-31            31         152.0           31
3  2020-04-30            30         121.0           30
4  2020-05-31            31          91.0           31
5  2020-06-30            30          60.0           30
6  2020-07-31            31          31.0           31
7  2020-08-31            31           NaN           27
8  2020-09-30            30           NaN            0
9  2020-10-31            31           NaN            0
10 2020-11-30            30           NaN            0
11 2020-12-31            31           NaN            0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @MrFuppes. If I do this, what's my best method to have all the results in a single column after? Ideally I'd like to have the days in the current month in the same column as daysinmonths

Comment: @visualnotsobasic: you mean like a Series of string? Or lists? It's unclear to me how the days in the current month (a scalar value) refers to the datetime column?

Comment: sorry, i'll clarify. i'm looking to just have a single additional column as an end product, where all past months would display the number of days in the month and any date in the current month would dynamically display number of days elapsed in said month

Comment: @visualnotsobasic: ok made an edit, let me know if that is what you need ;-)

Comment: thank you so much, trying now and will respond ASAP